# How to share a login between two sites without passing tokens around (Web-SSO)

Tags: oauth-2.0, oauth, authorization, single-sign-on, openid

I have two sites, one of which is essentially embedded into the other, although they have to be loaded from different URLs. They both access the same backend API. I want the user to log in once and be able to access the API in the embedded site without having to log in again. Essentially, I guess this would be Web-SSO. To complicate things even further, the outer site is a legacy PHP site with a backend server, the inner is a single-page react app.

I'm looking for a way to pass the login from the outer site to the inner site, without actually passing a login token around e.g. as an URL parameter, which would probably not be safe.

Essentially what I'm looking for is something Site A can safely give to site B, that will tell the authrisation server "Site A is authorized, and Site A trusts Site B, so it's OK to give Site B a token too"

Does such a mechanism exist? Some people have suggested OAuth2 and OpenID to me, but in all the documentation I've read, I haven't found any description of this use case. To me, this looks like OAuth2 in reverse. All examples I have seen concern the use case "Site A wants to access Service X, so it needs to authenticate with the Auth server Y, to get a token that will let it access the service". A second site wasn't part of the picture in any of the examples I could find.

Is OAuth2 even the right technology for this, or do I need something else entirely? How does one implement this use case?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you just want/need SSO. Since if a user logged in in site A (or any *.domain.com or *.com that is registered as a "safe" application) it will also be logged into site B.

Essentially how this works is when the user is logged in there will be a cookie stored on this website and (not sure) also on the API login website. Then whenever the user tries to enter website B e.g. the application should check for a cookie on site B. If there isn't any cookie it will look for a cookie on the API login website. If there is it will automatically login (without credentials). This is basicly what you say.

> Site A can safely give to site B, that will tell the authrisation
> server "Site A is authorized, and Site A trusts Site B, so it's OK to
> give Site B a token too"

**This could be achieved** by using a third party like Auth0. Im currently trying to implement this in Symfony. So far not much success but since I searched alot for other SSO providers I think this is the best shot. Also for your needs I belive it will work good enough.

**Another option:**

Create a API authentication server yourself. This way you have full control over it. But you need to manage it all yourself, also the security. There are probably packages that help you alot but still, you need to figure out alot by yourself.

My advice is to check out Auth0 by just creating a free account. See what it can offer and try some things out.